# Why did Visual Studio Code stop recognizing Java projects in sub folders?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Today vscode stopped recognizing Java projects in sub folders. How can I make that happen without manually creating a workspace and manually importing each project. My file structure looks like:

```
parent
- project1
    ...
    pom.xml
- project2
    ...
    pom.xml
  ...
- projectn
    ...
    pom.xml
```

I used to cd to `parent` and issue `code .` and it would automatically discover and open all the Java projects. I've never needed a `.code-workspace` file before.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 4):

When you run across this kind of problem you can try to execute `java:clean java language server workspace` command in the command palette.

Comment: Thanks Steven, that did the trick :-)